# Parsing an variable in search field in AWK: issue with syntax

Tags: bash, awk

I read a few topics but still cannot solve the problem.

This is test file for example:

```
1:abc:100:/k/ll
2:abd:120:/k/gg
3:www:3:/k/ll
4:rrr:66:/k/gg
5:ddd:140:/k/ll
```

This is my code:

```
ZM=${2:-test}
VAR=$1
awk -F':' -v one="$VAR" '$4 ~ one $3 > 100' $ZM
```

I want for this script to write these lines, where the 3 field is greater than 100, and 4 field contains the string specified in the variable, eg. "ll".

For example:
./test.sh ll

Output:

```
1:abc:100:/k/ll
5:ddd:140:/k/ll
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your responses!

Comment: You're just missing the "and" part of your description: `$4 ~ one && $3 > 100` -- awk expressions use (basically) the same operators as C. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Expressions.html#Expressions

Comment: @glenn you may as well make that comment an answer

Comment: That is the answer.  Even if it is in a comment. block.

Answer (score -1):

FOR $3>100

```
 awk -v FS=":" -v one=$VAR '{if($3>100 && $4~one){print $0}}' my_file
```

FOR $3>=100 (since your output is different from your request)

```
 awk -v FS=":" -v one=$VAR '{if($3>=100 && $4~one){print $0}}' my_file
```

Comment: -1 no, this is not how to do this in awk, it completely misses the point of it's condition/action language. See @GlennJackman's comment for the right answer.

Comment: "condition/action language"?.Please discuss.Have you tested my command line to get the OP expected results?

Comment: A script that produces the expected output from a given input set is very close to the starting point for identifying a solution, it is a long way from the end point. Get the book "Effective Awk Programming" by Arnold Robbins and google "awk pattern action" and bear in mind the word "pattern" used in almost all awk documentation is misleading, the better word is "condition".